# suppress "number stored as text" warning in Excel VSTO with C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working in a Excel VSTO project with C#. 
For certain columns, I have set the NumberFormat to Text using

```
someCell.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
```

But when numbers do happen to be in these columns, Excel shows a green arrow with warning "Number Stored as Text". I want to suppress this warning message.

I know how to do that in Excel: Options -> Formulas -> in Error checking rules, uncheck "Numbers formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe". Is it possible to do this in C# code, and only to certain cells/ranges? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's (in VBA)

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection.Cells
    c.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
Next c
```

Seems like you can't address a whole range at once - have to loop through the cells

Comment: Thanks Tim! This seems promising! Now I am stuck in translating it to C#. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840349.aspx, xlNumberAsText is a constant. I have found that it is in the type of object. Now I have no idea how to get this object constant... Tried using "xlNumberAsText", but not working.

Comment: `XlErrorChecks.xlNumberAsText` if you have the Interop library referenced. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlerrorchecks