# PERFORMANCE - looping over cells - suppress “number stored as text” warning in Excel VSTO with C#

Tags: c#, excel, performance, vsto

I am populating a ListObject with data from a database, and am pre-formatting ListColumns which come from VarChar (& similar) as Text before inserting the data.

This works well, but some affected cells now are showing the 'Number Stored As Text' error.

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869098/1281429 suppresses the error correctly, but requires looping through all cells (as it is not possible to perform the action on a range).

Unfortunately for large ranges this is **unacceptably slow**.

(n.b. - if you do it manually in Excel it's lightning fast)

Here is a code snippet in C# (for a particular column):

```
var columnDataRange = listColumn.DataBodyRange
var cells = columnDataRange.Cells;
for (var i = 1; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    InteropExcel.Range cell = cells[i, 1];
    if (cell.Count > 1) break;

    if (cell.Errors != null)
    {
        var item = cell.Errors.Item[InteropExcel.XlErrorChecks.xlNumberAsText];
        item.Ignore = true;     
    }   
}
```

Does anyone know of a faster way of doing this?

(Or, more generally, a faster way of iterating through cells in a range?)

Hope someone can help - thanks.

Edit: this is a VSTO Application-Level add-in for Excel 2010/2013.

Comment: Is this something that can only be done in code? Could you do this before hand in Excel itself?

Comment: Hi @rhughes.  Not really: this is part of a VSTO Add-in I have built for my end users to get data from databases in a managed way.

Comment: yeah, it's pretty common taks. There are various ways how to handle with this including looping over all cells (extremely slow!). What I usually use is just multiple the **whole** range 1. I save the number 1 somewhere in the spreadsheet, copy, paste special -> Operation=Multiply. Of course, all by code and **you don't need to use Select at all**

Comment: Hi @PetLahev. I'm trying to suppress errors, not multiply values so I'm not quite sure how your comment helps. Have I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure - you are going from a database to an Excel export? Are you creating a new, clean spreadsheet or overwriting existing data in an existing spreadsheet?

If you are overwriting data in an existing spreadsheet, I would first clear the columns and format the columns in Excel (programmatically of course). It is likely old data and new data going into the same space are causing type issues.

So something like:
`thisExcel.xlWorksheet.Range[yourrange].Value = ""`
`thisExcel.xlWorksheet.Range[yourrange].NumberFormat = choseyourformat`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401(v=office.15).aspx

You should be able to apply that to a larger area.