# Suppress "Number Stored as Text" warning in Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel

This question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868926/suppress-number-stored-as-text-warning-in-excel-vsto-with-c-sharp), but the answer requires looping over all the cells, which can be slow (as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784227/performance-looping-over-cells-suppress-number-stored-as-text-warning-in-e) question.)

Using Excel (manually), I have created a file, disabled the "Numbers formatted as text" rule in Options->Formulas, and saved the file. When I open the file in Excel (manually) now, the option is disabled. However, when I open the file using C#, the option is enabled again.

Question: How can I disable this option in the file, so that it is disabled when I open it in C#?

Comment: How do you open the file in C#? It's not like there is a standard managed API :))

Comment: Using VSTO. Application excel = new Application(); Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);